# As a .NET library author, what framework version should I target?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-assembly

I'm a bit confused on compatibility between .NET assemblies. On the one hand it seems like any 4.X assembly can reference any other 4.Y assembly, since both use the same CLR version. However when using NuGet to package assemblies, I see different behavior. When a client includes my NuGet package this only succeeds if they target the same or a newer version of .NET, otherwise I get a message such as "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

Does this mean I should target the lowest 4.X .NET version? Or can I rig my NuGet package so that it will install into any 4.X project, and I can keep targeting the newest 4.X version?

Comment: You should target the .NET version that you *need* to get your code to compile.  So yes, lowest, usually 4.0 or 4.5.  And not lie about it when you pick the framework target for your project.  If you pick 4.0 then you do run the risk that somebody tries to use it on an XP machine and you probably did not test that :)  It is up to you to decide how much support you are willing to give.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to check what key authors use and follow their examples, such as JSON.NET. Then learn but by bit why they make such choices. You are not the first one, so don't trouble yourself much.